# How to fix PHP amqp?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I've next error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/amqp.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/amqp.so: undefined symbol: amqp_basic_qos in Unknown on line 0

I've installed rabbitmq-server, PHP amqp extension, here is my librabbitmq:

```
miraage@newpc2:~$ ls -la /usr/local/lib | grep rabbit
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      25 марта 31 14:40 librabbitmq.so -> /usr/lib/librabbitmq.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      46 апр.   1 16:08 librabbitmq.so.1 -> /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.so.1
```

What I do wrong?

// upd

Ubuntu 13.04
PHP 5.4.9

I've installed librabbitmq via
`sudo apt-get install librabbitmq0`

Comment: Could you post more information? PHP version and librabbitmq version. Did you compile it?

Comment: Take a look at this tread: https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/issues/87

Comment: Read, nothing helped me.

Comment: First of all, there are pretty nice and definite quite how to report a problem at https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp#how-to-report-a-problem. Make sure compiled extension look for library in /usr/local/lib rather then /usr/lib/. Also, in some rare cases, as reported on SO, changing file permissions may help. P.S. if your problem will not be solved, contact me via skype (same user name as here) and we'll try to go through all process together. In Russian.

Comment: Also, provide php-amqp version you installed and in a which way (pecl, from source or deb) you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem . it is looking for `librabbit.so` and `librabbit.so.1` in `/usr/lib` directory instead of /`usr/local/lib` directory. I copied `libraabit.so and librabbit.so.1` in `/usr/lib` directory , **restart apache and its working now**.

Comment: There is no `librabbit.so` and/or `librabbit.so.1` anywhere. However, there is `librabbitmq.so`, usually in /usr/lib if you compile the extension from the source files.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem was in incorrect system, someone broke my Ubuntu on job.
I even was not able to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 - and after clear installation php-amqp was installed perfectly from PECL.

Thanks you all for help.